# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml when @produces is removed

Tags: jersey-2.0

[ERROR   ] MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class XX.XX.XXX, genericType=class is coming , if we remove the @produces annotation in JERSER2 rest service

This error is resolved when I start using @produces annotations, however for my swagger to work, we need to remove this annotation.

Isnt that JERSEY2 should be able to accept it without explicitly mentioning @produces in the endpoint ?

Please advise, any input would be appreciated.

Comment: It's depends on the `Accept`. If the client sends an `Accept` that the server handle handle, then you will get this error. If the client sends `Accept: application/xml` and  you use `@Produces("application/json")` you have safe guard and client will just get a 406 Not Acceptable error, which is the correct error. If you are getting the above error it means that the client sent a `Accept: application/xml` and your server is not setup for it. Maybe you need an `@XmlRootElement` on your model bean.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. However, I solved this issue by passing in content-type header param for the endpoint. It is now able to resolve the response in swagger-ui